# Why does Behat throw an error on "ucan <username>"?

Tags: 7, users, drush, testing

In our Behat tests we delete all test users in a `before-hook`. But sometimes our Behat test throws an error like:

> Could not find a user account with the name vN8eLbrd!
>
> Could not find a user account with the name some.wiredstuff-registration-test_10706!

Strange thing is that I get this user name direct from database. So I do not understand why this `drush ucan` command can not find it.

```
/** @beforeScenario */
  public function before($event) {
    $this->getSession()->getDriver()->resizeWindow(1280, 1024);

    // List all Scenarios which create the testuser.
    $scenarios = array(
      'Register for testing with Credit-Card',
      'Register for testing with Paypal',
      'Register for testing with valid Direct-Debit',
      'Register for testing with invalid Direct-Debit',
      'Access my subscriptions page',
      'Register for testing',
      'Register and use link from registration mail',
      'Logout',
      'Log in with username and password',
      'Recover your password'
    );

    $users_to_clean = array(
      'test@muster.de',
      'shaka@test.de',
      'some.wiredstuff+behat-registration-test@gmail.com'
    );

    $title = $event->getScenario()->getTitle();

    // Delete Testuser before the Scenario.
    if (in_array($title, $scenarios)) {
      foreach ($users_to_clean as $mail) {
        $user = user_load_by_mail($mail);
        if ($user) {
          shell_exec('drush ucan ' . $user->name . ' -y');
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Problem with not deleted users is that other tests fail because a test user already exists.

Do you have a clue why this happens?

Comment: Are you sure the users exist? Can you check the order the tests are run?

Comment: In this line `$user = user_load_by_mail($mail);` I get the user with `user_load_by_mail()` - so I am pretty sure that the user exists. Otherwise `if` would be false and do not run `shell_exec`.

Answer (score 3):

While debugging with xdebug in PhpStorm I figured out that `user_load_by_mail($mail)` loads cached users. `user_load_by_mail()` uses this function:

```
/**
 * Load multiple users based on certain conditions.
 *
 * This function should be used whenever you need to load more than one user
 * from the database. Users are loaded into memory and will not require
 * database access if loaded again during the same page request.
 *
 * @param $uids
 *   An array of user IDs.
 * @param $conditions
 *   (deprecated) An associative array of conditions on the {users}
 *   table, where the keys are the database fields and the values are the
 *   values those fields must have. Instead, it is preferable to use
 *   EntityFieldQuery to retrieve a list of entity IDs loadable by
 *   this function.
 * @param $reset
 *   A boolean indicating that the internal cache should be reset. Use this if
 *   loading a user object which has been altered during the page request.
 *
 * @return
 *   An array of user objects, indexed by uid.
 *
 * @see entity_load()
 * @see user_load()
 * @see user_load_by_mail()
 * @see user_load_by_name()
 * @see EntityFieldQuery
 *
 * @todo Remove $conditions in Drupal 8.
 */
function user_load_multiple($uids = array(), $conditions = array(), $reset = FALSE) {
  return entity_load('user', $uids, $conditions, $reset);
}
```

But it calls this function without `$reset == true`. That's why it uses cached user objects and tries to delete an already deleted user.

I fixed this lines with:

```
// Delete Testuser before the Scenario.
    if (in_array($title, $scenarios)) {
      foreach ($users_to_clean as $mail) {
        $users = user_load_multiple(array(), array('mail' => $mail), true);
        $user = reset($users);
        if ($user) {
          shell_exec('drush ucan ' . $user->name . ' -y');
        }
      }
    }
```